# Codeigniter Insert Item into array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hi i have array and it looks like this :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'id' => string '12' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Mary' (length=4)
```

now, for every ID I pass them to another query to get another information from another table, how do I add the result query for each ID to add in the array such as this :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
      public 'OfficeName' => string 'Records' (length=7)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'id' => string '12' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Mary' (length=4)
      public 'OfficeName' => string 'Accounting' (length=10)
```

Comment: Please can you update your portion of code from where you will get this details so it would be easier to explain you that what you will do

Comment: It is better if you could explain "another query", "another information" and "another table" means so that we could have an idea of the logic you need to help you!!

Comment: don't know your query but maybe you should take a look at "join" https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

once you have the $OfficeName you just need to do a foreach loop like so:

```
foreach ($array as $k) {
    $k->OfficeName = $OfficeName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Array**

```
$ar = array(
        (object)array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'John'
            ),
        (object)array(
                'id' => '12',
                'name' => 'Mary'
            )
    );
```

supposedly you are going to query to get the office name and assuming the result of the query would be something like this:

**Result Array**

```
$ar2 = array(
        (object)array(
                'id' => '1',
                'OfficeName' => 'Records'
            ),
        (object)array(
                'id' => '12',
                'OfficeName' => 'Accounting'
            )
    );
```

to insert values from second array to the first array, I would have done something like this:

```
$new_arr = array();
    foreach ($ar as $value) {

        foreach ($ar2 as $row) {
            if ($row->id == $value->id) {
                $temp_ar = (object)array(
                    'id' => $value->id,
                    'name' => $value->name,
                    'OfficeName' => $row->OfficeName
                );
                array_push($new_arr, $temp_ar);
            }
        }            
    }
```

the $new_arr will have the contents of result array together with the first array.